# Java Telebot удаление inline клавиатуры, с запоминанием предыдущей

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram, telegrambots

Прошу поддержки в поиске алгоритма запоминания состояний клавиатуры.

Хочу организовать многоуровневое меню:

Послал клавиатуру => юзер нажал на кнопку => текущая клавиатура и сообщение удалилась => появилась новые.

Но в новой клавиатуре есть кнопка назад, и должна открыться предыдущая клавиатура и так весь стек.
Вложенностей не много: Страна => Регионы => События в регионах.
Как бы по лучше это организовать к ответу код не обязательно прикреплять достаточно самой мысли. Я могу послать и удалить, мой вопрос как запомнить и хранить.

Если вопрос уже был прошу указать.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем что-то хранить если в кнопку *Назад* можно указать что именно открыть?

У каждой кнопки есть текст и `callbackData` куда можно передать любую строку.

Сначала делаете несколько кнопок выбора страны указав в `callbackData` что-то наподобие `open_country id1`.
После нажатия кнопки вы получаете этот текст,смотрите что он начинается с `open_country` вытаскиваете `id` и понимаете какую страну выбрал пользователь, отрисовываете регионы этой страны с данными `open_region id2` и кнопку Назад с данными `open_all_countries`.

При нажатии на регион вы получаете id региона, отрисовываете кнопки с событиями и зная к какой стране принадлежит регион делаете кнопку назад с данными `open_country id1`

Comment: в принципе логично буду так пробовать я думаю юзать какой ни будь стэк или подобие кэша